# Как поменять значения 2-х переменных местами, не создавая третью, и всё это через output_buffer?

Tags: php

Как создать 2 переменные и поменять их значения местами, не используя 3-ю используя output_buffer ?

Comment: Это учебное задание, или у вас какой-тодругой реальный вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `output_buffer`:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
ob_start();
echo $a;
ob_start();
echo $b;
$a = ob_get_clean();
$b = ob_get_clean();
var_dump($a, $b);
```

Без него:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
list($a, $b) = array($b, $a);
var_dump($a, $b);
```

Для чисел можно использовать следующее:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$b = $a ^ $b;
$a = $a ^ $b;
$b = $a ^ $b;
var_dump($a, $b);
```

Comment: @ALLIGATOR, возможно, стоило написать более развернутый ответ? Сейчас, к сожалению, времени для этого не хватает. Если будут нужны комментарии, то либо позже, либо кто-то другой объяснит что здесь происходит

Comment: Супер ! Первый вариант - то что надо ! ) Спасибо огромное ! )